# Animating number counter effect - animation not smooth

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I have some UI which requires a number to start from 0 and then count up to a specified max integer. Here is the basic animation:

[image]

To do this I created the following view:

```
public struct AnimatableNumber: View {
    @State private var animatedValue: CGFloat = 0

    let maxNumber: CGFloat
    let font: SwiftUI.Font
    let animationDuration: Double

    public init(maxNumber: CGFloat,
                font: SwiftUI.Font,
                animationDuration: Double = 2) {
        self.maxNumber = maxNumber
        self.font = font
        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
    }

    public var body: some View {
        Text("\(Int(maxNumber))")
            .font(font)
            .foregroundColor(.clear)
            .modifier(AnimatingNumberOverlay(number: animatedValue, font: font))
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            .fixedSize()
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: animationDuration)) {
                    animatedValue = maxNumber
                }
            }
    }
}

private struct AnimatingNumberOverlay: AnimatableModifier {
    var number: CGFloat = 0
    let font: SwiftUI.Font

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get {
            number
        }

        set {
            number = newValue
        }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.overlay(Text("\(Int(number))").font(font))
    }
}
```

Which is declared simply like this:

```
AnimatableNumber(maxNumber: number, font: SwiftUI.Font((Style.font(.chronicle80))))
```

Generally it works, however quite often the animation is not at all smooth. For example:

[image]

Note here how it animates to 45, then stops then goes straight to the max.

This behaviour is sporadic so wondering what I can change in my view to ensure a smoother animation consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a timer to get the desired effect.

```
func animate() {
    let interval = duration / Double(value)
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: true) { timer in
        tracker += 1
        if tracker == value {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

And you would call this inside the onAppear() event.

```
struct AnimateableNumber: View {
    let value: Int
    @State private var tracker = 0
    let duration = 0.5
    
    var body: some View  {
        Text("\(tracker)")
            .onAppear() {
                animate()
            }
    }
    
    func animate() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution and it runs smoothly every time. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, having just tested further, I have come across the same issue with this implementation as well. i.e. animating up to a certain number, stopping, and then continuing the animation...